# Kurento tutorial magic mirror example doesn't work

Tags: kurento

I'm trying to run the magic mirror example from kurento-magic-mirror.

The video is working, but I can see no hat on the faces from the video.
You can the media stream on both ends when connecting to `https://localhost:8443/`, but no add-on hats, as if the filter isn't running at all.

The example is running with `npm start -- --ws_uri=ws://kms_host:kms_port/kurento` and my server already has the installation requirements as in [here](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/node/tutorial-magicmirror.html).

What could be the problem and how can I test that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue can happen when your kurento server unable to load image files, specified by your client.
By default, the magic-mirror example assumes that both kurento and node.js servers are running locally. The image is passed to Kurento server by URL and the default one is `https://localhost:8443/img/mario-wings.png`. But if you moved your kurento server somewhere outside, it's unable to reach your localhost by trying to fetch `https://localhost:8443/img/mario-wings.png`.

You can try to hardcode any publicly available image url of supported type instead of one located on your localhost.

The place, where the overlay image url is assigned in the magic-mirror example is https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/blob/bf718c50e4a77df258aa5faaa95915d52bae3f4e/kurento-magic-mirror/server.js#L244

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem for me

Comment: In the latest code the overlay image URI is set on js/index.js line 33, as part of a call to getopts.  Also, be sure to shift-reload -- for me, the hello example's index.js was still resident even despite normal reloads.  The demo still doesn't work for me, but hardcoding the hat image and shift-reloading seems to get me closer